# Why there is undefined on fulfilled promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, undefined

Can you explain me something?

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(true) {
      resolve('succes')
    } else {
      reject('failure')
    }
  }, 4000)
})

promise1.then(result => console.log(result))
```

Why after that i got 'succes' on console and something like this

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
```

Why there is undefined if my promise returning 'succes' string value? This is beacause of setTimeout nesting? How could I fix this?

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works ok. Resolved into the `succes` and logged `succes`. _Btw it's succes**s**._

Comment: Because your promise didn't return anything - e.g. `console.log` returns undefined

Comment: We really need a canonical for "What does console.log return? Why is it when I use it I get undefined?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by doing following adjustments:

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const stat = true;
    if(stat) {
      resolve('success')
    } else {
      reject('failure')
    }
  }, 4000)
})

promise1.then(
    result => {console.log('resolve', result); return result;},
    result => {console.log('reject', result); return result;}
)
```

you will have both log and promise return value on dev tools;

**WHY?**

`undefined` is the result of the implicit return value the callback (`return;`), when a function doesn't return anything explicitly, js engine will add implicit `return` statement to the end of function body.

Comment: A tip about this answer is that `then` is responding to `resolve` stat and there's no handler for `reject` stat. the `then` part should edited to `.then(result => {console.log('resolved:', result); return result;}, result => {console.log('reject:', result); return result;}
)`

Answer (score 1):

@
Mateusz W

1- The first log '**success**' comes from the 'console.log(result)' that you have written.

2 -The second log '**Promise {: undefined}**' is refering to the '`promise1.then(result => console.log(result))`', because the 'then' function return itselelf a promise that resolves
the result that you return inside it (in your case you return nothing inside **then**).

To be sure verify the following code :

```
promise1.then(result => console.log(result)).then(result1 => {})
```

you will obtain the following result

```
succes
undefined
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
```

The undefined after the success is the one that you find in your '**Promise {: undefined}**'

that correspond here to **result1**.

Do not confuse with this `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}` that you see here (result of my code) because this is referring to the **second** then that I chained to your **then**

**In summary**: you may were confused and thought that the `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}` that you saw in console  is referring to you **promise1** const.
No it is not, it is the return of the **then** function.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, you aren't showing the code where you get

```js
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
```

But I imagine it could look something like this:

```js
promise1.then(result => {
   console.log(result)
   console.log(promise1); // this line here
})
```

If you do this instead:

```js
promise1.then(result => {
   console.log(result)
   console.log(promise1); 
   return result; // now this line here
})
```

Then you will see:

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: "succes"}
```

Comment: OP probably just typed their exact code into the console, and the console gave them the return value of the last line…

Comment: @deceze - but the promise isn't fulfilled at that point - so they can't see a `Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}` using that, they'd see a `Promise{<pending>}`

Comment: It might be a live-updating object/they only see that when expanding it after it *is* fulfilled?

Comment: @Adam "*but the promise isn't fulfilled at that point*" [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440) https://i.imgur.com/zTwcGTG.png

Comment: @deceze - was certainly my first thought as well. But I checked before I put that in my answer, this is not the current behavior in Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. Although I know realize maybe the OP meant something other than console.